# LVM, EXT4, mount points etc. I'm not even sure how to determine what the issue might be

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ext4, lvm2

I have a media server that used to work: 4 disks, EXT4, as a single LVM with 5 shares.

Working through other tutorials, when I execute the "lsblk" command this is what I see:

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─Fantasia-Fantasia 253:0    0  9.1T  0 lvm
sdb                   8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
└─Fantasia-Fantasia 253:0    0  9.1T  0 lvm
sdc                   8:32   0  1.8T  0 disk
└─Fantasia-Fantasia 253:0    0  9.1T  0 lvm
sdd                   8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk
└─Fantasia-Fantasia 253:0    0  9.1T  0 lvm
sde                   8:64   1 14.9G  0 disk
├─sde1                8:65   1 14.2G  0 part /
├─sde2                8:66   1    1K  0 part
└─sde5                8:69   1  667M  0 part [SWAP]
sr0                  11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

The boot drive is "sde" the rest of them are all full disks that are part of the LVM "Fantasia".

I don't see any files, but everything seems to be mounted, but I don't know what it SHOULD look like for it to be correct, and if not correct, how can I go about fixing it.

This is from a media server that I'd LIKE to recover rather than have to rebuild from scratch, but at this point I don't have a lot to lose, so if there are techniques I could use to try to, erm, I don't know recover the lvm information from a superblock? Jargon? Is there a way to even determine what the problem is and if it's something which can be fixed?

Tinkering with file systems is not for the faint hearted, I know, but my inability to even articulate, technically, makes even searching for possible answers challenging. It has been suggested that the "filesystem header is gone". Ok, if that's true, is there a way to confirm that or recover it? etc.

Kind of "crying out to the internet" here hoping someone can hear my plea... so thanks in advance...

Comment: It looks like you might be using LVM but this is not mounted.  What is the output of **pvs;vgs;lvs;df**

Comment: or even, `mount /dev/Fantasia/Fantasia /mnt`, and your `/etc/fstab`